# Loop through url's with R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest

I need to download a series of Excel files from URL's that all look as follows:

```
http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=01&EventId=31
http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=02&EventId=31
...
http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=87&EventId=31
```

I've got some of the building blocks inside the loop, such as:

```
for(i in 1:87) {
    url <- paste0("http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=", i, "&EventId=31")
    file <- paste0("Data/myExcel_", i, ".xlsx")
    if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file) 
}
```

**My problems**:

1. I need the `seq` to prepend the 0 (I tried `sprintf` with no luck)
2. I also want to import the Excel files, skip the first two rows and append them on after the other (they also have the same columns)

## Update

@akrun solution works well. But it turns out not all my Excel files have the same number of columns:

```
map(files, ~read.xlsx(.x, 
                         colNames = FALSE,
                         sheet = 1, 
                         startRow = 4,
                         )) %>%
  bind_rows

Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column `X1` can't be converted from numeric to character
```

I think this error actually points to the unequal number of column. I tried adding `fill = NA` (when testing `map_df()`), but it didn't help.

Comment: FWIW, provided you're not trying to make $,  "elections alberta" actually goes out of its way to inform you they allow personal and educational scraping. Please try to be kind and add in a `Sys.sleep(5)` tho. There's no need to download files faster than that.There's also a _really_ good chance one email could end up giving you a ZIP file or even a set of SQL to load these up w/o scraping. But, hey, nice try with `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm pretty new to web scraping. I didn't know one could ask for SQL access.  The example.com was more to shorten the link and make it fit in one line in SO than anything else!

Comment: Ohh and I learned the `if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file)` from your nuclear animation example! Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create it with `sprintf`

```
paste0("http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=", sprintf("%02d", 1), "&EventId=31")
#[1] "http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=01&EventId=31"
```

In the loop,

```
for(i in 1:87) {
  i1 <- sprintf('%02d', i)
   url <- paste0("http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=", i1, "&EventId=31")
   file <- paste0("Data/myExcel_", i, ".xlsx")
   if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file) 
}
```

Assuming that the files are downloaded in the working directory

```
files <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)
library(openxlsx)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(files, ~read.xlsx(.x, sheet = 1, startRow = 3))  %>%
      bind_rows
```

Or as @hrbrmstr mentioned in the comments, `map_df` can be used which returns a single dataset

```
map_df(files, ~read.xlsx(.x, sheet = 1, startRow = 3))
```

#### Update

Based on the comments from OP, there seems to be a difference in column class for some of the datasets.  In that case, `bind_rows` gives an error.  One option is to use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
map(files, ~read.xlsx(.x, sheet = 1, startRow = 3))  %>%
      data.table::rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: if you're already using `purrr` why not `map_df`? (serious q … curious if you've noticed performance issues or odd behaviour/etc).

Comment: @hrbrmstr  I thought about that.  But, if there are unequal number of columns it could break then `bind_rows` have the option  to `fill`

Comment: hrm. `map_df()` has always filled for me, too, but I also try to only use it with `list` output any more (it's noticeably faster than data frames, esp if returning alot of small ones)

Comment: Thanks! This almost works.  See update to post... yes I have unequal no. of col.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel  I think it is an issue with the column class difference in one of the `list` elements.  For e.g. `df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = as.character(6:10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
 df2 <- data.frame(A = 7:12, B = 8:13)
 bind_rows(df1, df2)#
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id)`  You can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` ie. `rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)`

  Column `B` can't be converted from character to integer

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel  It is not clear whether the column changed into character based on a single element or not.

Comment: I did try using `readr` with `col_types = cols(.default = "c")` instead of `read.xlsx`. Didn't help.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel  May be there is some element in one of the pages that convert the column to character.  Try with `rbindlist`.  It should work

Answer (score 3):

downloading and reading in 1 loop. Hopefully, the columns are aligned if not use something like `plyr::rbind.fill` instead of `do.call(rbind, list)`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:87, function(n) {
    url <- paste0("http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=", 
        sprintf("%02d", n), "&EventId=31")
    file <- paste0("Data/myExcel_", n, ".xlsx")
    if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file) 
    readxl::read_excel(file, skip=2)
    Sys.sleep(5)
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `regmatches`

```
 num=sprintf("%02.0f",1:87)
 urls=rep("http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=01&EventId=31",87)
`regmatches`(urls,regexpr("\\d+",urls))<-num
 urls[87]
[1] "http://example.com/orResultsED.cfm?MODE=exED&ED=87&EventId=31"
```

To have all the files:

```
 files <- paste0("Data/myExcel_",num , ".xlsx")
```

to download the files:

```
  mapply(function(x,y)if(!file.exists(x))download.file(y,x),files,urls)
```